# Get more than 20 last messages

Tags: twitter

Twitter API documentation says that I can get only 20 last messages ([proof link](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-friends_timeline)).  I'm just wondering if there is any other possibility to get more messages, for example - "all the messages from specific point in time".

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's about the Twitter _API_. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can specify `count`, which can be upto 200 and number of pages as well which allows you to retrieve upto 3200 status messages. And `since_id` allows you to retrieve messages after that particular message.

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml?count=100&page=5&since_id=23323
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameters in the link you've pasted. There's a parameter `count` that allows you to get up to 200 messages in one call. If you want more then that you can change `since_id` parameter value to get even older entries or use `page_id`.

Answer (score 0):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline

See the `count` parameter.

For example:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=someuser&count=50
```

That would get 50 messages, instead of the default 20.